# What is correct link for adding GeoServer WFS to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoserver, arcmap, wfs, data-interoperability

What is the correct URL to enter in ArcCatalog WFS parameters when adding a WFS layer from GeoServer into ArcMap?

Here's a link to our GetCapabilities document:

https://weaveprod.ucdp.utah.edu/geoserver/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities

I am using ArcMap 10.1 and experiencing the same problem [described here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73186/how-to-configure-geoserver-wfs-to-work-with-arcgis-for-desktop).  When I try to add WFS layers from GeoServer, "Feature Types" is blank.  That post says it is a bug with 10.1.  However, I added WFS from GeoServer not long ago, so I'm sceptical that the answer is to applicable to 10.2.  The only thing that changed was our GeoServer location.

I was able to bring in WFS layers from:

`http://www2.dmsolutions.ca/cgi-bin/mswfs_gmap?version=1.0.0&request=GetCapabilities&service=WFS`.

Although that is not GeoServer, I previously had GeoServer WFS working fine.

Here's an image of one URL I tried (which was:

`https://weaveprod.ucdp.utah.edu/geoserver/sf/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature`

No matter how I change it, no layers are coming up in feature types.  There shouldn't be any problem with my WFS layers because I can preview them as WFS through GeoServer.

[image: Adding WFS in ArcMap]

Comment: I just tested this using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop with your service URL and I see the same issue.

Comment: I think when I did this I had to specify the layer in the URL and could only add one at a time

Comment: Interesting that it doesn't work at 10.2 either.  Thank you very much for checking.  Also, I tried using a url to only one layer, but have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to add the data.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1, using the Data Interopability Connection, and I was able to bring in the bugsite feature class.

URL: https://weaveprod.ucdp.utah.edu/geoserver/ows

Parameters: 
[image]

Results:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

When defining URL try to delete everything after a questionmark 
i.e. only:

`https://weaveprod.ucdp.utah.edu/geoserver/ows?`