# Connect ArcMap (Interoperability Tool) to GeoServer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoserver, wfs, data-interoperability, getcapabilities

I have GeoServer (2.8.5) and multiple layers on it. If I want to edit layers in QGIS everything works fine (auth / show layer catalog / load layer / edit layer / save changes).

If I attempt doing the same in ArcGIS (10.2) with the Data Interoperability tool I struggle on getting the capabilities document. The URL is the same but I get following error:

(old image, url's not correct in the image, WFS instead of WMS)

[image]

I tried different styles in the URL like /geoserver/wfs? , /geoserver/wfs?request=getcapabilities but nothing seems to work. I've also tried connecting with /geoserver/ows? like mentioned in [What's the correct link for adding GeoServer WFS to ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84426) but that fails too.

Anybody has an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please always provide errors as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches.  Is there a service URL to a public GeoServer WFS that gives this error?  If so, please include it in your question.